# why is my h1 tag a link in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a mock page of **Facebook** as my first project using **HTML**, **CSS**, and **JavaScript**. For some reason, when I am trying to make a headline using a `<h1>` tag, it comes out as a link. I do not want that, just a regular heading would be nice. I cannot seem to figure out what I did wrong. I have been stuck for quite a while, I even had to delete some of my previous code to figure it out. At the moment, I have a index.html page, a main.css page, and a reset.css page.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Social Media Clone</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo-area">
            <a href="index.html">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"</a>Chris
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="example.html"</a>Home
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-links"> 
            <ul class="quick-options">
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"</a><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"</a><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"</a><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="privacy">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-area">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="search">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1>Chris</h1>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Because all of your a tags are malformed

Comment: All of your `a` tags are not syntactically correct: `<a href="chloe.html"</a>` They should look like `<a href="chloe.html">with text here if needed</a>` not to mention your icons should be within the a tag.

Comment: Copy and paste your code into the W3 Validator (https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and fix the mismatched tag errors that the validator shows.

Comment: Did anyone notice there are no h3 tags at all? Odd question

Comment: there is no h3 tag

Comment: Voted to close. Invalid HTML and no `<h3>` tag in the example. Unable to reproduce the problem. etc.

Comment: Thank you Henry7720!!!!! and Adil B for showing me a new tool

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Henry7720 above, just close off your `a` tags. This works in JSFiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Social Media Clone</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo-area">
            <a href="index.html">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"></a>Chris
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="example.html"></a>Home
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-links"> 
            <ul class="quick-options">
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"></a><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"></a><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="chloe.html"></a><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="privacy">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-area">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="search">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <h1>Chris</h1>
</body>
</html>
```